# Lagrange Polynomials with Derivatives (lowest order polynomial)

Tags: polynomials, interpolation, lagrange-interpolation

I need to find the lowest order polynomial, $P(x)$, that satisfies the following conditions using Lagrange polynomials:

$P^{'}(x_{0}) = f_{0}^{'}$

$P^{'}(x_{1}) = f_{1}^{'}$

$P^{'}(x_{2}) = f_{2}^{'}$

$P^{'}(x_{3}) = f_{3}^{'}$

with $x_i \neq x_j$ when $i \neq j$

I understand how to find the Lagrange polynomials, but I am not sure how to satisfy the derivative conditions. Is a quadratic or cubic interpolation needed? Thank you.

Comment: Since all conditions are for first derivatives, you can just interpolate $P'$ and integrate it to get $P$.